# Find all available percentages which in result will be equal to variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, percentage

I need to generate all available percentages which when multiplying will be equal to the variable.

For example:

```
minUnit = 0.5
sumUnits = 1.5

const availableUnits = [0.5, 1, 1.5]
```

I need to get all percentages, where `percentage * sumUnits = one of the availableUnits numbers.`

The range is `[1, 100]`.

For example for such availableUnits the result will be:

- 33% = 0.495
- 67% = 1.005
- 100% = 1.5

The example of data:

```
[
{
    units: 1,
},
{
    units: 1,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
}]
```

What I tried:

```js
const selectedRows = [
{
    units: 0.5,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
},
{
    units: 0.5,
}
];

function getAvailableDivisors() {
    const minUnit = _.minBy(selectedRows, 'units')?.units || 0
    const sumUnits = _.sumBy(selectedRows, 'units')

    let availableTargetUnits = []

    if (selectedRows.length > 1) {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i += 1) {
            const percentage = i / 100

            for (let j = minUnit; j <= sumUnits; j += minUnit) {
                if (percentage * sumUnits === j) {
                    availableTargetUnits.push(i)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        availableTargetUnits = [100]
    }

    return availableTargetUnits
}

console.log(getAvailableDivisors());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe it's not what you're looking for, each value y = Math.round(x * 100 / sumUnits) where x is in the array availableUnits. I don't see what you're expecting with your method. Please specify.